# Xamarin Forms Android Linker problem after upgrading MsBuild version

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, msbuild

We recently updated our build version from MsBuild 15 (from Visual Studio 2017) to MsBuild 16 (from Visual Studio 2019).

After the change the release build for our Xamarin.Forms.Android app stopped building, while the debigging and test versions still build and run fine. The culprit seems to be the linker, which is set to "SDK only" in release and off in the other configurations, with linker set to off the release build also works, but the apk size doubles.

Here is the error message I get with verbosity set to diagnostics, which basically says a duplicate key was inserted into a dictionary, but nothing else

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004: System.ArgumentException: Ein Element mit dem gleichen Schlssel wurde bereits hinzugefuegt. [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.GetTypesInModule(ModuleDefinition module) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.FindType(TypeDefinition type, String fullname) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.GetHelperType(TypeDefinition type, String suffix) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.PreserveAdapter(TypeDefinition type) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.PreserveJavaObjectImplementation(TypeDefinition type) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.ProcessType(TypeDefinition type) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.DispatchType(TypeDefinition type) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseTypes(ICollection types) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblies) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.Process(LinkContext context) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask() [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5): error XALNK7004:    bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() [C:\Projekte\AuditDb\AuditApp\AuditApp.Android\AuditApp.Android.csproj]
```

Any tips how to further investigate the issue would be appreciated.