# Xamarin Forms Android linker problem in VS 2022

Tags: xamarin, linker-errors

While trying to Archive a Xamarin Android project using VS 2022 Version 17.0.5 with linker set to "SDK Assemblies Only" I get the error XALNK7004. If I set linker to None, the apk is built successfully.
It seems the same problem in [Xamarin Forms Android Linker problem after upgrading MsBuild version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882552/xamarin-forms-android-linker-problem-after-upgrading-msbuild-version).

```
This is logged:
Touching "obj\Release\110\stamp\_AndroidXCecilfy.stamp".
XALNK7004: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.GetTypesInModule(ModuleDefinition module)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.FindType(TypeDefinition type, String fullname)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.PreserveInvoker(TypeDefinition type)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MarkJavaObjects.ProcessType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.DispatchType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseTypes(ICollection types)
at Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseTypes(ICollection types)
at Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
Done building project "OfficeTrack.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.`enter code here`
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: The steps to reproduce are:
-select Release/Any CPU/OfficeTrack.Droid ,right click the droid project and click Archive.
When link is set to None, it succeeds. When is "SDK Assemblies Only" it fails.
I tried apk and bundle formats, with and without aapt2 but not helped.
This project has a huge amount of nugets and maybe there is really a problem but the error message doesn't include any information about which library is causing it.

Comment: Does this problem happen when you try other demos?

Comment: I am sure it is just because of this huge project but it can be archived in VS2019 version 16.11.9. I accept that the problem is in my project but would like the linker message to display which library is problematic, otherwise, I would need to exclude all the hundreds of assemblies and try  adding one by one. It will be a nightmare. Is there a file or folder to be checked to help me identify which libraries are causing this issue ?

Comment: `I am sure it is just because of this huge project but it can be archived in VS2019 version 16.11.9. `  Did you also set Linker to `SDK AssembliesOnly` on VS 2019 version 16.11.9 and build successfully?

Comment: Yes, with VS 2019 I can create the apk with linker set as "SDK AssembliesOnly".
I need to solve this problem to be able to replace VS 2019 by 2022.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For this problem, you can go [visual studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/) for further help.